# Are there any ways to convert a symmetric weight matrix into undirected weighted graph without looping?

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, networkx

From a particular dataset I obtained the pandas dataframe object and calculated the correlations between columns of this df.

The next step is to move from this correlation matrix to a weighted graph, where weights are taken from this matrix.

Since I have about 100 datasets that are big enough, I would prefer not to use looping for this purpose (or do it in a smart way).

The main problem with the command "stack()" is that the graph becomes directed, it includes both edges [(x,y):weight0] and [(y,x):weight0]. I would like to get rid of those duplicates. Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx



df1 = df1.corr()
links = df1.stack().reset_index()
links.columns = ['var1', 'var2','value']
links = links.loc[(links['var1'] != links['var2'])]
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(links, 'var1', 'var2', 'value')
```

Comment: `The main problem with the command "stack()" is that the graph becomes directed, it includes both edges [(x,y):weight0] and [(y,x):weight0]`

I think this is what makes the graph undirected. If `[(x,y):valueA]` and `[(y,x):valueB]` were different, it means that the cost is different if you go from x to y than y to x. You can see those 2 links as just one with that weight0 value, this is, undirected and weighted graph

Comment: Further I plan to calculate some centrality measures, and this redundant information will increase the time of calculation quite a lot and thus I would like to get rid of these "duplicates".

Answer (score 0):

You can go more directly from the correlation dataframe (which is really just a square numpy array with the trim of a) to networkx:

```
correlation_matrix = df1.corr().values
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(correlation_matrix,create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

if you want to make the diagonal 0 before making the graph insert the following code between the two lines above, noting that np.fill_diagonal works in-place:

```
import numpy as np
np.fill_diagonal(correlation_matrix, 0)
```

Comment: In this case the graph will be unweighted, since correlation matrix will be taken as an adjacency matrix. I was looking for a method that transforms the correlation matrix into weighted graph

Comment: from: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_numpy_matrix.html 

"The matrix entries are assigned with weight edge attribute."

Comment: But here is used from_numpy_matrix(not to_numpy_matrix, which you sent the link to) without "weight" attribute. It would be great if we had something like this.

Comment: yes, sorry for that. I think you can use the code above if you pass create_using = nx.DiGraph()
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html#networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix